# Linking GLEW and GLFW3 on mac on command line

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw, glew

So basically, i'm on mac.

I installed glew and glfw3 on command line via homebrew.

Now these libraries with the .h files are inside /usr/local/include and i can include them without error (intellisense even finds methods and stuff).

The thing is, unlike stdio.h string.h iostream ecc. including them is apparently not enough.

As soon as i build the program, this message appears on the console:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glewInit", referenced from:
      _main in es-97eafd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know what to do, do you know how to properly use these libraries?

Comment: Did you link them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps you need to do to make glew and glfw3 work.

I assume you have already installed these with brew as such:

```
brew install --universal glew
brew install --universal glfw3
```

Next when you compile your code, you need to include the headers with `-I` flag and link to the above libraries with the `-l` flag as such:

```
-I/usr/local/include  -lGLEW -lglfw
```

A sample makefile should look something like one shown below, assuming we are developing an OpenGL app in `main.c` with these libraries.

```
BIN = hellot
CC = clang++
FLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -UGLFW_CDECL -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
INC = -I/usr/local/include
LOC_LIB = -lGLEW -lglfw
FRAMEWORKS = -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit
SRC = main.c

all:
    ${CC} ${FLAGS} ${FRAMEWORKS} -o ${BIN} ${SRC} ${INC} ${LOC_LIB}
```

I have included a [sample project on Github as well](https://github.com/dmsurti/hello_triangle) which demonstrates the above by rendering a 3D triangle, the hello world of graphics. [See the same Makefile listed above here](https://github.com/dmsurti/hello_triangle/blob/master/Makefile).

Comment: is the include flag necessary? What's its purpose? usr/local/include is already recognised by the #include directive and the headers are included correctly